# How to get Add_PreviewMouseDown working with 2 windows and .Show()?

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I have a program with a main window (powershell wpf/xaml). That program does a check for files and opens a second window, if something is missing it must have a link to the folder, i use `.Add_PreviewMouseDown({ })` for that. That works, but if i run a second check, window 2 gets the same "link to folder" as window 3. How can i get it to work, that links of window 2 dont get updatet?

i already tried to get dynamic Label Names and PreviewMouseDown's but that isnt enough.

```bsh
$Script:WindowNumber += 1
$WindowName = "Win$WindowNumber"

$CEMessage = '<Label Name="CEFout' + $WindowNumber + '"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,288,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" FontSize="14" ToolTip="Fileserver Folder" >
                    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="Bureaublad\Machine Folder">&#10799; CE:</Hyperlink>
             </Label>'

New-Variable -Name "BijlagenWPF$WindowNumber" -Value ($BijlagenWPF = @"
<Window 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="Bijlagen" Height="420" Width="250" Icon="$Icon" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="True">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="240">

        $CEMessage

    </Grid>
</Window>
"@ -as [XML])

$NR2=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader (Get-Variable | Where-Object Name -eq "BijlagenWPF$WindowNumber").Value)
New-Variable -Name $WindowName -Value ([Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $NR2 ))

$BijlagenWPF.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]")  | ForEach-Object { 
    New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value (Get-Variable | Where-Object Name -eq $WindowName).Value.FindName($_.Name) -Force 
}

(Get-Variable | Where-Object Name -eq "CEFout$WindowNumber").Value.Add_PreviewMouseDown({[system.Diagnostics.Process]::start("$Desktop\$Machine\Fileserver\manual\bijlagen")})

(Get-Variable | Where-Object Name -eq $WindowName).Value.Show()
```

[This is a screenshot of the 2 windows with opened link. Now the link in the first window (2532-163) is the same as the second window (2532-164). But has to be 2532-163 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1a8f.png)

Comment: To be clear, if you create a standalone wpf program with the same XAML and subscriptions...the same happens? It appears (to me) you need to isolate whether these problems are from bad WPF operations or bad powershell.

Comment: After the second check (one window is already open with a link that works by the Add_PreviewMouseDown) a second window opens with the good link for that window, but the first window will also get the same link. What i need to know is which code has to be different, that the link of the first window will stay the same as when it was created.